# Env vars to change app name in project.json and set runtime vars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I need to generate two apps from the same codebase (e.g. "pro" and "lite" versions). There are a lot of questions here about this but none I found involve `node` or `electron`.

I have only used `env` in development in very simple ways and after searching around, I haven't seen any mention of being able to use them in a deployed application.

So two tasks:
**1. Changing the name of the app**

So, using the `package.json` file with `electron builder`, I've tried to change the `productName` like this:

```
  "productName": process.env.APP_NAME,
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "package-mac": process.env.APP_NAME='Bingo' electron-packager . --overwrite  --platform=darwin --arch=x64  --prune=true --out=release-builds"
}
```

But that didn't work. Also saw this construction but it also didn't work:

```
  "productName": '${process.env.APP_NAME}',
```

Am I on the wrong track here?

**2. Vars for use at runtime**
To do the "pro" & "lite" thing, I need at least a flag to know how to configure things.
Are `env` vars in anyway suitable for this?

I guess if I am able to change the app name, I can access that at runtime but it seems like I am missing something important with all this.

Comment: As far as I'm aware you would have to build a shim/pass-through program that would  alternate versions based on input. a.e. a `.bat` file or a separate `node` app that would determine and run the build differently. This is because there's no JS involved when it gets up and running for distribution, it's all configuration, so setting a flag *in* the config isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Using [dot-json](https://github.com/maikelvl/dot-json), you can have npm scripts like:

```
  "productName": "Bingo",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "package-mac": "echo $APP_NAME; dot-json package.json productName $APP_NAME --indent 2; electron-packager . --overwrite  --platform=darwin --arch=x64  --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  }
```

In Terminal, maybe, you can run

```
 $ APP_NAME='Bingo Pro' npm run package-mac
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wasn't able to get that to work – got the `"Usage"` man page from `dot-json`.