# How does Electron determine application identity for requestSingleInstanceLock?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

We're trying to build our Electron app under a different name, with a different `appId` so that we can run it alongside our original app - but it always triggers Electrons ['second-instance'](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-second-instance) - at least on Windows where I'm testing.

What do we need to do to make Electron that these are two entirely separate applications?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem using `electron-packager`. Changing the executable name via `appname` is not sufficient but changing the `name` in `package.json` also did it.

We were using `dot-json` from our build system after packaging to change it. See [this answer about using `dot-json` from npm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56878511/543682).

For the question about what is used for identity: As far as i could determine electron uses a lockfile in `%USER_DATA_DIR%\%APPNAME_FROM_PROJECT_JSON%\lockfile`. On my machine for an app called `electron-shell` it becomes `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\electron-shell\lockfile`. It is possible to look this up using the Sysinternals Process-Explorer.

Comment: Hey @sanosdole Thanks for your answer! I tried that but that didn't do it for me with `electron-builder` on Windows even though you'd think it would. Can I ask, what OS did you test this on?

Comment: We tested only on Windows with Electron 10.1.1.We changed the `name` in `resources\app\package.json` in the packaged application after packaging.

Comment: I added a description on how electron determines identity for `requestSingleInstanceLock`

Comment: Great info, thanks for sharing! That said, I think it's highly inadvisable to use your method of changing it _after_ packaging, except in development circumstances.

Comment: We could change it directly in the package.json before packaging, but we are using the same project.json for different application brandings. So we would need to change it back to a general name after packaging to prevent source control from going wild. That is what we' ll do if the packaging gets more complex like using ASAR archives.
Of course if the tooling would support this during packaging it would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

**What we did to resolve this was set the `nsis.guid` ourselves to predefined UUIDv5 string.**

You can repackage an application without having it trigger `'second-instance'` by manually setting the `GUID` - at least on Windows.

Changing the `appId` or `name` should change this [according to the docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#guid-vs-application-name). It does change the `GUID`, as confirmed via the Windows registry (`regedit`), but it wasn't enough.